# Вёрстка сайта слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, плагин

С помощью каких плагинов можно сделать сайт похожим на [этот](http://buckymaler.com/global/#0) .

Думаю тут можно использовать `slick-slider` только сделать так, чтобы он реагировал на `scroll и swipe`, но как сделать меню которое есть на этом сайте (прилаживаю картинку)?

[image: А именно секция слева]

Comment: не знаю как на десктопе, но на мобильнике ничего толкового по ссылке нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно загнать в перспективу контентную часть сайта при открытии меню, сделать это можно с помощью такого кода, набросал на быструю руку, стили уже подгоните под себя

```js
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $('.container').toggleClass('perspective');
  $('.site').toggleClass('black_bg');
  $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.main_site {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px 100px 10px 10px;
}

.site {
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ddd;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

.perspective {
  transform: translateZ(-1800px) translateX(-50%) rotateY(45deg);
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform .4s, -webkit-transform .4s;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.black_bg {
  background: black;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

nav.active {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}

nav li {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_site">
  <div class="site black_bg">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Это контент сайта</h1>
      это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum
      для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и,
      в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">МЕНЮ</div>
  <nav class="main_manu">
    <ul>
      <li>Главная</li>
      <li>О нас</li>
      <li>Портфолио</li>
      <li>Контакты</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```